# what's the different about those two situation about hibernate's saveOrUpdate()

Tags: java, hibernate

```
saveOrUpdate() does the following:
•if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
•if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
•if the object has no identifier property, save() it
•if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
•if the object is versioned (by a <version> or <timestamp>), and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
•otherwise update() the object
```

this clause:

```
"if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception"
```

with this:

```
•if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
```

I think, in those two situation, there are already have a object this this identifier. the same...

Answer (score 1):

In this clause:

```
if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
```

"the value assigned to a newly instantiated object" means the default value that Java gives to an instance variable. For 'String' variable it would be 'null' and for 'int' variable it would be '0'.

---

Next I'll present an example. It doesn't make much practical sense but it proves the rule.

Let's get an object with identifier '0' from the database. The auto-increase is on for this identifier. We use session 1 to get the DAO and then close the session.

Now let's initialize session 2 and get the same DAO with identifier '0'. We save the object retrieved using session 1 to the database with session 2. We can use save or saveOrUpdate methods to save the object. DAO is successfully saved with a new id to the database.

When reproducing the example with object identifier '1' we get "NonUniqueObjectException" when saving the object and the database remains unchanged.

NonUniqueObjectException is given as stated:

```
if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
```

We have proven that the instance variables are an exception to the "same identifier" rule.